# Neo4j: Relationships

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am currently working on a project which aims to use graph databases, in particular Neo4j. My question concerns how to create the "Relationship" relations between the different nodes, for information, the data to be used is in CSV format, in this case, I will import data that is in .csv format, first we create the nodes based on this data, then we move on to creating the relationships between the different nodes.

I tried a lot of code but we didn't get the desired result regarding the creation of relationships between nodes.

I used the following code:

```
Load csv with headers from "file:///airports.csv" as airports create (a1: Airport {label: airports.label, city: airports.city, state: airports.state})
match (n) return (n)

Load csv with headers from "file:///flights.csv" as flights create (n: Flights {flight: flights.flight, airline: flights.airline, capacity: flights.capacity})
match(n) return(n)
```

while the nodes are created.
but neither do relationships. in addition I had the following message: (no changes, no records) this after the execution of the following code:

```
Load csv with headers from "file:///flights.csv" as flights match (a: Flights {flight: flights.flight}), (b: Airport {label: flights.arrive}) create (a) –[r : Arrivals] -> (b)
match (n) return (n)

Load csv with headers from "file:///flights.csv" as flights match (a: Flight { flight: flights. flight}), (b: Airport {label: flights. depart}) create (a) –[r : Departures] -> (b)

match (n) return (n)
```

To inform you, I have two tables of data whose extension .csv one for airports and the other for flights.
How should we create the relationship that exists between airports and flights? I don't know where is the error.

Comment: Go back to your csv files and check that flights.arrive or flights.depart columns are matching with airports.label.  Your query to create the relationship looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jose_bacoy to check that all of these fields actually match each other.

Also. you don't need to process flights.csv three times. You can use a MERGE statement that will either create the node or match it if it already exists. Then with one pass through the file, you can:

1. Create the flight (or match it)
2. Create the relationship to the departure airport
3. Create the relationship to the arrival airport

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file" as flights
MERGE (n: Flights {flight: flights.flight, airline: flights.airline, capacity: flights.capacity})

MERGE (n)–[:Departures]->(b: Airport {label: flights.depart})

MERGE (n)-[:Arrivals]->(c: Airport {label: flights.arrive})
```

This will also create the Airport nodes if they do not exist.